# Is there an event name for this action?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a ScrollView event in xamarin that is triggered when the user forces scroll up and scroll is already at top? Many apps uses this as the "command" to update the page.

Comment: The default ScrollView doesn't fire any events, you can use this [PullToRefreshLayout plugin by James](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout)

Comment: @Shan There is the `Scrolled` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no `PullToRefresh` property or `RefreshCommand` for a `ScrollView` built into Xamarin.Forms. However, It does exist on `ListView` as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#Pull_to_Refresh), which you might be able to use instead depending on your needs.

Also, it does look like there is a `PullToRefreshLayout` [opensource project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout) created by James Montemagno you might be able to use to easily implement pull to refresh with a `ScrollView`, but it has been a while since it's last been updated.

Comment: I'm trying to update a ListView, so your answer is very usefull. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scrolled` event handler. If the `ScrollView` is already positioned at the top of the contents and the user "pulls down" then `Y` amount will be either 0 or negative (I know this will work on Android and iOS, not sure about UWP and others).

```
scroll.Scrolled += (object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (e.ScrollY <= 0)
    {
        // scrolled when already at top of list
    }
};
```